# On concentration inequalities

Tags: textbooks, graduate-education

I would like suggestions for a good text on concentration inequalities (examples here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality). I am looking for sources (texts) that can give strong intuitions in applying these bounds for practical problems. Sources (not limited to textbooks) which have practice problems applied to CS theory or applied math style is ideal for my purpose.

Disclaimer: I am not "yet" an educator, but a researcher who wants to get a good introduction to it before I apply them to my research.

Comment: You might want to give a brief description of what you mean by the term "concentration inequalities" or provide a link to a discussion of it.  I am not familiar with the term, and perhaps the other readers are not familiar with it too.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Inequalities-Zhengyan-Lin/dp/364243777X

Comment: This is a question that would probably get more answers in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Loève's *Probability Theory*, $\S$9 for example, might be worth a look.

Comment: Did you check external readings and the references linked in the wiki page?